# Object parameter in other function file don't work --> "Notice: Undefined property:..."

Tags: php

I have folowing php code and class in different files:

/ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-controller/AnmeldenCtrl.php:

```
<?php
        include "../ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-database/Datenbank.php";
        include "../ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-model/Benutzer.php";

        $db = new Datenbank();
        $benutzer = new Benutzer();
        $benutzer->setBenutzername($_POST["bname"]);
        $benuName = $benutzer->getBenutzername();
        echo $benuName;
        $benutzer->setPasswort($_POST["passwd"]);
        $pwd = $benutzer->getPasswort();
        echo $pwd;
        if ($db->loginBenutzer($benutzer)) {
            echo "<p>Zugang erlaubt</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p>Zugang eigentlich nicht erlaubt ...</p>";
        }
    ?>
```

/ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-database/Datenbank.php

```
<?php
include "../ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-database/IDatenbank.php";

class Datenbank implements IDatenbank {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    /**
     * Diese Methode meldet einen Beunutzer an das 
     * Zeiterfasssungssystem an
     * @param benuter :Benutzer
     * @return true falls Login erfolgreich, sonst false
     * 
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @see IDatenbank::loginBenutzer()
     */
    public function loginBenutzer($benutzer) {

        $passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort;         // error
        $hashPW = $this->createHash($passwort);

        if( password_verify($hashPW, $gespeicherter_hash) ) { 
            return true; 
        } else { 
            echo false; 
        } 
    }

    public function createHash($password) {

        return $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }
.
.
}
?>
```

on line commented with "error" I become this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: Benutzer::$getPasswort in C:\xampp\htdocs\eclipseWS\TimeManager\application\ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-database\Datenbank.php on line 24

But the call in AnmeldenCtrl.php "$pwd = $benutzer->getPasswort();" works fine.

Any helps please and thanks...

Here the last class

/ch-ffhs-webe-timemanager-model/Benutzer.php

```
<?php

class Benutzer {

private $benutzername;
private $passwort;

public function __construct() {

}

/**
 * benutzername
 * @return String
 */
public function getBenutzername(){
    return $this->benutzername;
}

/**
 * benutzername
 * @param String $benutzername
 * @return Benutzer
 */
public function setBenutzername($benutzername){
    $this->benutzername = $benutzername;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * passwort
 * @return String
 */
public function getPasswort(){
    return $this->passwort;
}

/**
 * passwort
 * @param String $passwort
 * @return Benutzer
 */
public function setPasswort($passwort){
    $this->passwort = $passwort;
    return $this;
}
```

}
   ?>

Comment: I could resolve the problem. I forget the clamp at the end of functionname --> $passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort(); ... ups, a shame mistake.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `()` for the function call.

```
 $passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort;
```

should be

```
 $passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort();
```

There is no property `getPasswort` on your class, it is a function.

Answer (score 0):

There was a little oversight in your code:

```
    //$passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort;         // YOU SHOULD BE CALLING YOUR GETTER METHOD HERE:

    $passwort = $benutzer->getPasswort();         //<== WITH THE BRACKETS
```

Otherwise, your Code seems quite OK...

Comment: Thanks I have see.. ;)